# problem with isdigit function and while loops in c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, std

I'm new to c++ and trying to code a v simple program where it uses a while loop for user to input numbers where it adds those numbers together but as soon as a word or letter is input it breaks and outputs the sum of, excluding any alphabetical input.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char ans;
    int ans1 = 0;
    cout << "Enter numbers to be added" << endl;
    cin >> ans;
    while (isdigit(ans)) {
        cin >> ans;
        ans1 = ans1 + ans;
    }
    
    cout << ans1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It's probably something that's been staring me right in the face, but I'd appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: You read characters, but then add them as integer values. Keep in mind that ASCII `'0' == 48`.

Comment: The problem is that it adds the ASCII value of the letters to the result as well.

Comment: *The problem is that it adds the ASCII value of the letters to the result as well* --Isn't that what you wrote?  `ans1 = ans1 + ans;`?

Comment: Provide some sample input, what you expect from it, and what you actually get.